# script logging, file per script

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

Shell script logging is fairly easy with `set -x` and `tee` but I want to have script 1 call script 2 and have both log execution in their own log file. Right now, script 1 includes the logs generated by script 2 but I really only want the commands of script 1 in the script 1 log and the commands of script 2 in the script 2 log.

Below is what I have tried:

#### `script1.sh`

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x

LOG=script1.log.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
{
  ls script1.sh
  set +x
  ./script2.sh
  set -x
  ls script2.sh
} 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG
```

#### `script2.sh`

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x

LOG=script2.log.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
{
  date
} 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG
```

What this produces is two log files but `script1.log.date` contains all the output from both scripts and `script2.log.date` contains only the script2 output.

With the code above script1.log.data contains:

```
+ ls script1.sh
script1.sh
+ ./script2.sh
+ date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
+ LOG=script2.log.20170418151625
+ + tee -a script2.log.20170418151625
2>& 1
+ date
Tue Apr 18 15:16:25 EDT 2017
+ ls script2.sh
script2.sh
```

However, I want to contain just:

```
+ ls script1.sh
script1.sh
+ ./script2.sh
+ ls script2.sh
script2.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

In script2 you are using `tee -a` which duplicates the output, once to file and once to stdout.

In script1 you capture all the output (including duplicated output from script2) and log it to the file and to stdout.

If the terminal output isn't important, just skip the `tee` in script2.

If you want to split the logging in script1, so that the output from script2 is not captured, while output from all other commands is. Then you have to open and redirect to other output channels. Tends to be bothersome.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `tee` in `script2`, the output goes both to the logfile and to the standard output of the script when it was executed. Since the standard output of the script is being logged in `script1`, `script1` will also see the output.

I assume you also want both scripts’ outputs to show up on the console when you run `script1`? If not, then I see no reason to use `tee` at all. If so, then you need to save the original stdout descriptor in `script1`, so that you can redirect `script2` to use it and not the logging descriptor.

I have not tested the code below, so take it with a grain of salt, but something like it should work:

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -x

{
  LOG=script1.log.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
  {
    ls -al
    set +x
    ./script2.sh 1>&3
    set -x
    ls -al
  } 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG
} 3>&1
```

What I intend to do above is save a copy of file descriptor 1 (the original standard out, like a console) as file descriptor 3, and then override the logging on the call to `script2.sh` to use this copy instead of the default standard out.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. script1.log.<date> still contains everything in script2.log.date. 

`
$ cat script1.log.20170418113405 
+ ls -al script1.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 slanglois eng 164 Apr 18  2017 script1.sh
+ ./script2.sh
+ date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
+ LOG=script2.log.20170418113405
+ tee -a script2.log.20170418113405
+ 2>& 1
+ date
Tue Apr 18 11:34:05 EDT 2017
+ ls -al script2.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 slanglois eng 87 Apr 17 14:59 script2.sh
`

where I'm tying to not have the script2.log execution in the script1.log.date file.

Sorry for the formatting. Back ticks are not working.